# Код ответа 102 от сервера

Tags: api, http

В каком случае имеет смысл возвращать код ответа 102? В частности, меня интересует ситуация. У сервера есть 2 эндпоинта:

```
/health
/ready
```

Первый возвращет 204 и делает это сразу после запуска приложения. Второй возвращает 204, но по проществии времени. В течение этого времени происходит загрузка данных и подготовка к работе. Какой код ответа должен возвращать сервер? Я обратил внимание на [102](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#102). Корректно ли это?

Comment: Формально - да, корректно. Вопрос в том, как это обработают ваши клиенты.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич наверное, в данном случае, это история про другое. 102 возвращают для того, чтобы сбросить счетчик ожидания на клиенте. Видимо, правильнее 503 или 202. Я склоняюсь к 503.

Comment: ну формально и 102 ничего не нарушает. Другое дело, что подобного рода реализации лично я нигде не видел, а разработчики клиентов (будь то мобильные приложения, или там frontend) как правило люди консервативные в этом плане. Сложно предугадать, как отреагируют.

Comment: Каким боком тут может быть 503??

Comment: HTTP 503 Service Unavailable сервер недоступен

Comment: Вот именно - нечего ему тут делать.

Comment: @Qwertiy какой тогда? И почему нечего ему тут делать?

Comment: @Qwertiy, Gitlab когда поднимается, отдает 502 `Whoops, GitLab is taking too much time to respond.`. С точки зрения прокси Nginx это правильно. А 102 тут не уместно, 102 для того, чтобы клиент не отвалился по таймауту, а услужливо ждал, слушая соединения. Если у ТС сервер сможет потом "дослать" в то же соединение 2xx, то уместно, а если там разрыв, то 102 - не корректно. На педивикию лучше не ориентироваться в таких вопросах, вот [корректное трактование](https://httpstatuses.com/102) - взято со [спеки](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2518#page-59)

Comment: @TotalPusher, когда поднимается гитхаб, он не работает. А для обрабатываемого запроса пятисотые коды стопроцентно неуместны.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, соглашусь. 502 - потому что прокси тупой, а тут приложение само понимает, когда поднимется. Ну тогда 102 => 204 вполне нормальный вариант. Современные клиентские либы умеют обрабатывать 206 и клеить запросы, а по 308 отправляют снова POST на новые адреса. Но можно проверить как отрабатывает ситуацию curl, потому что многие клиенты используют libcurl, и соответственно наследуют поведение.